# Gestures Builder isn't installed on my emulator

Tags: android-emulator, gestures

I've tried several emulators with different SDK versions (2.1 and 2.3), and neither one has the Gestures Builder application installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to install it.

In Eclipse

- File->New->Android App
- Choose to create an app from existing source
- select something along the lines of android-sdk-windows\samples\android-7\GestureBuilder
- Build and install...