# GestureBuilder code

Tags: android

Hi guys
       I want to have a gesturebuilder in my application.That is i want the user to be able to enter gestures and i will use them.I checked the gesture builder code on the internet but was unable to find the source code for it.What i am having to do now is to enter gestures on the emulator using the gesture builder application and push them on to the raw folder using file explorer.This is not very user friendly and i want to integrate the gesturebuilder app into my application.How do i do this.
Is there any other way to store what the user writes in the screen.Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - basic gesture detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

Answer (score -1):

```
<installation-directory>/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-2.1/samples/GestureBuilder
```

Comment: sorry, i am an idiot :) I didn't know what to do with the code. If anyone else is interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740056/gestures-builder-isnt-installed-on-my-emulator