# adding swipe gesture to my calendar app - android

Tags: android

I'm a beginner at best at developing apps. I'm sorry if this is going to be a repeat question I've been trying for days now to figure this thing out.

So what I have is a calendar (which was a example I found around the internet). What I wanted to do is make a color coded calendar to match my schedule at work so I added a few things to make that work and changed the look of it with a few different drawables. All that went somewhat fine. I even was able to figure out how to add when selecting a certain day it takes you to google calendar to the same day to schedule an event. But for the life of me I cannot figure out this gesture part.

So below I will provide with my code and hopefully one of you fine people can give me some pointers. I like to think I'm close. I've built the gesture library with "next" and "previous" saved into it and put this in my raw folder that I created. Right now I set it up so it will toast the prediction name but it isn't doing the toast. I do see the yellow line where I swipe left or right. Ultimately I want this to do what's in the onClick method's for next and previous a little below the gesture method.

```
    package com.examples;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
import android.gesture.Prediction;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.trhodes.workcalendar2.R;

public class SimpleCalendarViewActivity extends Activity implements
        OnClickListener, OnGesturePerformedListener {
    private static final String tag = "SimpleCalendarViewActivity";
    Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
    private Button currentMonth;
    private ImageView prevMonth;
    private ImageView nextMonth;
    private GridView calendarView;
    private GridCellAdapter adapter;
    private Calendar _calendar;
    private int month, year;
    private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";
    GestureLibrary mLibrary;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_calendar_view);
        // new GestureDetector(this, this);
        _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
                + year);

        selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this
                .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

        prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
        prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        currentMonth = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));

        nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
        nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

        // Initialised
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);


        GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

        mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!mLibrary.load()) {
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);

        // We want at least one prediction
        if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 1.0
                && gesture.getStrokesCount() > 1) {
            String what = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < predictions.size(); i++) {
                if (predictions.get(i).name.equals("next")
                        || predictions.get(i).name.equals("previous")) {
                    what = predictions.get(i).name;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(what.equals("next")){

//              Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
//                      + month + " Year: " + year);
//              setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
                Toast.makeText(this, what, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }else if(what.equals("previous")){

//                  Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
//                          + month + " Year: " + year);
//                  setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
                Toast.makeText(this, what, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }}}


    /**
     * 
     * @param month
     * @param year
     */
    private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == prevMonth) {
            if (month <= 1) {
                month = 12;
                year--;
            } else {
                month--;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);
            setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Previous", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (v == nextMonth) {
            if (month > 11) {
                month = 1;
                year++;
            } else {
                month++;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);
            setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Next", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Inner Class
    public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
        private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
        private final Context _context;

        private final List<String> list;
        private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
        private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
                "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
        private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
                "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December" };
        private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
                31, 30, 31 };
        private int daysInMonth;
        private int currentDayOfMonth;
        private int currentWeekDay;
        private Button gridcell;
        private TextView num_events_per_day;
        private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;

        // Days in Current Month
        public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                int month, int year) {
            super();
            this._context = context;
            this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                    + "Year: " + year);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
            // setCurrentMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

            // Print Month
            printMonth(month, year);

            // Find Number of Events
            eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
        }

        private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
            return months[i];
        }

        private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
            return weekdays[i];
        }

        private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
            return daysOfMonth[i];
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        /**
         * Prints Month
         * 
         * @param mm
         * @param yy
         */
        private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
            Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
            // The number of days to leave blank at
            // the start of this month.
            int trailingSpaces = 0;
            int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
            int prevMonth = 0;
            int prevYear = 0;
            int nextMonth = 0;
            int nextYear = 0;

            // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // added this string to hold the results for which color workColor
            // will use
            // initialized with the word "clear" so string won't be empty
            String workColor = "clear";
            // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            int currentMonth = mm - 1;
            String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
            daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

            Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
                    + daysInMonth + " days.");

            // Gregorian Calendar : MINUS 1, set to FIRST OF MONTH
            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
            Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

            if (currentMonth == 11) {
                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                nextMonth = 0;
                prevYear = yy;
                nextYear = yy + 1;
                Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
                prevMonth = 11;
                prevYear = yy - 1;
                nextYear = yy;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                nextMonth = 1;
                Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            } else {
                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
                nextYear = yy;
                prevYear = yy;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            }

            // Compute how much to leave before before the first day of the
            // month.
            // getDay() returns 0 for Sunday.
            int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
            trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

            Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
                    + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
            Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
            Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

            if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && mm == 2) {
                ++daysInMonth;
            }

            // Trailing Month days
            for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
                Log.d(tag,
                        "PREV MONTH:= "
                                + prevMonth
                                + " => "
                                + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                                + " "
                                + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
                                        - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                        + i));

                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // added to the line below this code -> + "-" + workColor <-
                // was -> list.add(String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth -
                // trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET) + i) + "-GREY" + "-" +
                // getMonthAsString(prevMonth) + "-" + prevYear);
                // now -> list.add(String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth -
                // trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET) + i) + "-GREY" + "-" +
                // getMonthAsString(prevMonth) + "-" + prevYear + "-" +
                // workColor);
                list.add(String
                        .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                + i)
                        + "-GREY"
                        + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                        + "-"
                        + prevYear + "-" + workColor);
                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }

            // Current Month Days
            for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {

                // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // reusing david's calendar code here and resetting the date
                // every time it loops thru the "for" statement
                cal.set(yy, currentMonth, i); // yy = year, currentMonth =
                                                // month, i = day
                // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // //////////////////////////////////////////////
                // you will need to implement some code here that will count the
                // number of weeks
                // from a set date. So roughly it would say
                // weeksFromSetDate = setDate (count the weeks to) todaysDate
                // then weeksFromSetDate would take the place of
                // "cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)" below
                // in the "if" statement. So, if weeksFromSetDate is an even
                // number it will
                // have no remainder and go to the related "switch" statement.
                // otherwise it will go to the lower "switch" statement below
                // "else".
                // Currently if you run the code it will only give you the
                // number of the week
                // within the given month. So the order of the work weeks from
                // month to month will be off.
                // This is just to give you an example to work with.
                // //////////////////////////////////////////////

                // int ordinalDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
                // int weekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1; // Sunday =
                // 0
                // int numberOfWeeks = (ordinalDay - weekDay + 10) / 7;
                // System.out.println(numberOfWeeks);

                // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // added this "if" and "switch" statement
                // the "if" statement looks for odd or even weeks of the month
                // so, if the number of the week of the month has a zero
                // remainder after dividing by two is true go to switch
                // statement below

                if (cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) % 2 == 0) { // will find even
                                                                // week number
                    // the "switch" statement looks for the number of the day of
                    // the week
                    // so, if the number of the day of the week is 1, 2, 3, or 4
                    // then workColor will equal blue
                    // or , if the number of the day of the week is 5, 6, or 7
                    // then workColor will equal red
                    switch (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                        workColor = "blue";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                        workColor = "red";
                        break;
                    }
                    // if the number of the week of the month has a remainder
                    // after dividing by two then go to switch statement below
                } else { // will be an odd week number
                            // this switch statement will do the same as the one
                            // above with the exception that the workColor will
                            // change
                    switch (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                        workColor = "red";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                        workColor = "blue";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy + " "
                        + workColor);
                if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {

                    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // added to the line below this code -> + "-" + workColor <-
                    // was -> list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-" +
                    // getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                    //

                    // list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-" +
                    // getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy + "-" +
                    // workColor);
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-GREEN" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy + "-"
                            + workColor);
                    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                } else {

                    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // added to the line below this code -> + "-" + workColor <-
                    // was -> list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-" +
                    // getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                    // now -> list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-" +
                    // getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy + "-" +
                    // workColor);
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy + "-"
                            + workColor);
                    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
            }

            // Leading Month days
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
                Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));

                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // added to the line below this code -> + "-" + workColor <-
                // was -> list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-" +
                // getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
                // now -> list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-" +
                // getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear + "-" +
                // workColor);
                list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear + "-"
                        + workColor);
                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
        }

        /**
         * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
         * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
         * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
         * day.
         * 
         * @param year
         * @param month
         * @return
         */
        private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
                int month) {
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // DateFormat dateFormatter2 = new DateFormat();

            // String day = dateFormatter2.format("dd", dateCreated).toString();

            // if (map.containsKey(day))
            // {
            // Integer val = (Integer) map.get(day) + 1;
            // map.put(day, val);
            // }
            // else
            // {
            // map.put(day, 1);
            // }
            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day_gridcell, parent,
                        false);
            }
            // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
            gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
            gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

            // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

            Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
            Log.d(tag, "day_color " + list.get(position).toString());
            String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
            String theday = day_color[0];
            String themonth = day_color[2];
            String theyear = day_color[3];

            // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // added day_color[4] it holds the information on which work color
            // will be used in this method
            String theworkcolor = day_color[4]; // theworkcolor will be the
                                                // string that holds it
            // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
                if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
                    num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                    Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                    num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
                }
            }

            // Set the Day GridCell
            gridcell.setText(theday);
            gridcell.setTag(themonth + "/" + theday + "/" + theyear);
            Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + themonth + "/" + theday + "/"
                    + theyear);

            if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }

            if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE"))

                // added this if statement below to check if theworkcolor is
                // equal to "red"
                if (theworkcolor.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
                    // if theworkcolor equals "red" then make the text for the
                    // day red
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    // if not make it the text for the day blue
                } else {
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if (day_color[1].equals("GREEN")) {
                if (theworkcolor.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
                    // if theworkcolor equals "red" then make the text for the
                    // day red
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    // if not make it the text for the day blue
                } else {
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                }

                if (day_color[1].equals("GREEN")) {
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();// <== These 2 lines
                                                            // highlight current
                                                            // day of
                    if ((cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) == month)// <== current
                                                                // month
                                                                // only.

                        gridcell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.current_day);
                }
            }
            return row;
        }

        // Section below opens google calendar and puts the same date as date
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        // pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
            Date startdate = null;

            try {

                startdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy")
                        .parse(date_month_year);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            // String eventStartInMillis = (String) date_month_year;
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", startdate.getTime());
            String eventEndInMillis = null;
            intent.putExtra("endTime", eventEndInMillis);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
            return currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
            this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
            this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
        }

        public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
            return currentWeekDay;
        }

    }
}
```

also here is my xml if this may help. I believe I set this up right.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectedDayMonthYear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_top_header"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_bar"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#4682B4" >

        </Button>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/calendarheader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/blue_bg_with_text" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
                android:id="@+id/gestures" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
                android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true" android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical|center"
            android:layout_weight="0.66"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Press any day to schedule an event"
            android:textColor="#4682B4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I just wanted to thank you for your time in advance. Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated. I hope I was clear enough in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is the solution that I have come up with. I wanted to make sure that I get this posted that way the next person that may need help, this could possibly be of some use. Thanks to Maxim Efimov for his response got me going in the right direction. Also this YouTube video helped me a lot as well [GestureOverlayView tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5aWkmVJs-k)

So here is my working Code:

```
package com.examples;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
import android.gesture.Prediction;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.trhodes.workcalendar2.R;

public class SimpleCalendarViewActivity extends Activity implements
        OnClickListener, OnGesturePerformedListener {
    private static final String tag = "SimpleCalendarViewActivity";
    Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
    private Button currentMonth;
    private ImageView prevMonth;
    private ImageView nextMonth;
    private GridView calendarView;
    private GridCellAdapter adapter;
    private Calendar _calendar;
    private int month, year;
    private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";
    private GestureLibrary mLibrary;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
        View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.simple_calendar_view, null);
        gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
        gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
        gestureOverlayView.setGestureColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        gestureOverlayView.setUncertainGestureColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        // speeds up the reaction time a little
        gestureOverlayView.setFadeOffset(0);
        gestureOverlayView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
        mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!mLibrary.load()) {
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(gestureOverlayView);

        _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
                + year);

        selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this
                .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

        prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
        prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        currentMonth = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));

        nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
        nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

        // Initialised
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
        for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
            if (prediction.name.equals("next")) {

                if (month > 11) {
                    month = 1;
                    year++;
                } else {
                    month++;
                }
                Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: "
                        + "Month: " + month + " Year: " + year);
                setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
                return;
            } else {
                if (prediction.name.equals("previous")) {

                    if (month <= 1) {
                        month = 12;
                        year--;
                    } else {
                        month--;
                    }
                    Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: "
                            + "Month: " + month + " Year: " + year);
                    setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
                    return;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param month
     * @param year
     */
    private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == prevMonth) {
            if (month <= 1) {
                month = 12;
                year--;
            } else {
                month--;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);
            setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);

            return;
        }
        if (v == nextMonth) {
            if (month > 11) {
                month = 1;
                year++;
            } else {
                month++;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);
            setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);

            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Inner Class
    public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
        private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
        private final Context _context;

        private final List<String> list;
        private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
        private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
                "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
        private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
                "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December" };
        private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
                31, 30, 31 };
        private int daysInMonth;
        private int currentDayOfMonth;
        private int currentWeekDay;
        private Button gridcell;
        private TextView num_events_per_day;
        private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;

        // Days in Current Month
        public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                int month, int year) {
            super();
            this._context = context;
            this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                    + "Year: " + year);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
            // setCurrentMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

            // Print Month
            printMonth(month, year);

            // Find Number of Events
            eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
        }

        private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
            return months[i];
        }

        private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
            return weekdays[i];
        }

        private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
            return daysOfMonth[i];
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        /**
         * Prints Month
         * 
         * @param mm
         * @param yy
         */
        private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
            Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
            // The number of days to leave blank at
            // the start of this month.
            int trailingSpaces = 0;
            int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
            int prevMonth = 0;
            int prevYear = 0;
            int nextMonth = 0;
            int nextYear = 0;

            // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // added this string to hold the results for which color workColor
            // will use
            // initialized with the word "clear" so string won't be empty
            String workColor = "clear";
            // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            int currentMonth = mm - 1;
            String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
            daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

            Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
                    + daysInMonth + " days.");

            // Gregorian Calendar : MINUS 1, set to FIRST OF MONTH
            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
            Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

            if (currentMonth == 11) {
                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                nextMonth = 0;
                prevYear = yy;
                nextYear = yy + 1;
                Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
                prevMonth = 11;
                prevYear = yy - 1;
                nextYear = yy;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                nextMonth = 1;
                Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            } else {
                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
                nextYear = yy;
                prevYear = yy;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            }

            // Compute how much to leave before before the first day of the
            // month.
            // getDay() returns 0 for Sunday.
            int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
            trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

            Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
                    + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
            Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
            Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

            if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && mm == 2) {
                ++daysInMonth;
            }

            // Trailing Month days
            for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
                Log.d(tag,
                        "PREV MONTH:= "
                                + prevMonth
                                + " => "
                                + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                                + " "
                                + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
                                        - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                        + i));

                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // added to the line below this code -> + "-" + workColor <-
                // was -> list.add(String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth -
                // trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET) + i) + "-GREY" + "-" +
                // getMonthAsString(prevMonth) + "-" + prevYear);
                // now -> list.add(String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth -
                // trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET) + i) + "-GREY" + "-" +
                // getMonthAsString(prevMonth) + "-" + prevYear + "-" +
                // workColor);
                list.add(String
                        .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                + i)
                        + "-GREY"
                        + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                        + "-"
                        + prevYear + "-" + workColor);
                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }

            // Current Month Days
            for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {

                // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // reusing david's calendar code here and resetting the date
                // every time it loops thru the "for" statement
                cal.set(yy, currentMonth, i); // yy = year, currentMonth =
                                                // month, i = day
                // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // //////////////////////////////////////////////
                // you will need to implement some code here that will count the
                // number of weeks
                // from a set date. So roughly it would say
                // weeksFromSetDate = setDate (count the weeks to) todaysDate
                // then weeksFromSetDate would take the place of
                // "cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)" below
                // in the "if" statement. So, if weeksFromSetDate is an even
                // number it will
                // have no remainder and go to the related "switch" statement.
                // otherwise it will go to the lower "switch" statement below
                // "else".
                // Currently if you run the code it will only give you the
                // number of the week
                // within the given month. So the order of the work weeks from
                // month to month will be off.
                // This is just to give you an example to work with.
                // //////////////////////////////////////////////

                // int ordinalDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
                // int weekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1; // Sunday =
                // 0
                // int numberOfWeeks = (ordinalDay - weekDay + 10) / 7;
                // System.out.println(numberOfWeeks);

                // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // added this "if" and "switch" statement
                // the "if" statement looks for odd or even weeks of the month
                // so, if the number of the week of the month has a zero
                // remainder after dividing by two is true go to switch
                // statement below

                if (cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) % 2 == 0) { // will find even
                                                                // week number
                    // the "switch" statement looks for the number of the day of
                    // the week
                    // so, if the number of the day of the week is 1, 2, 3, or 4
                    // then workColor will equal blue
                    // or , if the number of the day of the week is 5, 6, or 7
                    // then workColor will equal red
                    switch (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                        workColor = "blue";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                        workColor = "red";
                        break;
                    }
                    // if the number of the week of the month has a remainder
                    // after dividing by two then go to switch statement below
                } else { // will be an odd week number
                            // this switch statement will do the same as the one
                            // above with the exception that the workColor will
                            // change
                    switch (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                        workColor = "red";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                        workColor = "blue";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy + " "
                        + workColor);
                if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {

                    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // added to the line below this code -> + "-" + workColor <-
                    // was -> list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-" +
                    // getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                    //

                    // list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-" +
                    // getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy + "-" +
                    // workColor);
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-GREEN" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy + "-"
                            + workColor);
                    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                } else {

                    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // added to the line below this code -> + "-" + workColor <-
                    // was -> list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-" +
                    // getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                    // now -> list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-" +
                    // getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy + "-" +
                    // workColor);
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy + "-"
                            + workColor);
                    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
            }

            // Leading Month days
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
                Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));

                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // added to the line below this code -> + "-" + workColor <-
                // was -> list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-" +
                // getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
                // now -> list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-" +
                // getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear + "-" +
                // workColor);
                list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear + "-"
                        + workColor);
                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
        }

        /**
         * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
         * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
         * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
         * day.
         * 
         * @param year
         * @param month
         * @return
         */
        private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
                int month) {
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // DateFormat dateFormatter2 = new DateFormat();

            // String day = dateFormatter2.format("dd", dateCreated).toString();

            // if (map.containsKey(day))
            // {
            // Integer val = (Integer) map.get(day) + 1;
            // map.put(day, val);
            // }
            // else
            // {
            // map.put(day, 1);
            // }
            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day_gridcell, parent,
                        false);
            }
            // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
            gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
            gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

            // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

            Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
            Log.d(tag, "day_color " + list.get(position).toString());
            String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
            String theday = day_color[0];
            String themonth = day_color[2];
            String theyear = day_color[3];

            // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // added day_color[4] it holds the information on which work color
            // will be used in this method
            String theworkcolor = day_color[4]; // theworkcolor will be the
                                                // string that holds it
            // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
                if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
                    num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                    Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                    num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
                }
            }

            // Set the Day GridCell
            gridcell.setText(theday);
            gridcell.setTag(themonth + "/" + theday + "/" + theyear);
            Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + themonth + "/" + theday + "/"
                    + theyear);

            if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }

            if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE"))

                // added this if statement below to check if theworkcolor is
                // equal to "red"
                if (theworkcolor.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
                    // if theworkcolor equals "red" then make the text for the
                    // day red
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    // if not make it the text for the day blue
                } else {
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if (day_color[1].equals("GREEN")) {
                if (theworkcolor.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
                    // if theworkcolor equals "red" then make the text for the
                    // day red
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    // if not make it the text for the day blue
                } else {
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                }

                if (day_color[1].equals("GREEN")) {
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();// <== These 2 lines
                                                            // highlight current
                                                            // day of
                    if ((cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) == month)// <== current
                                                                // month
                                                                // only.

                        gridcell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.current_day);
                }
            }
            return row;
        }

        // Section below opens google calendar and puts the same date as date
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        // pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
            Date startdate = null;

            try {

                startdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy")
                        .parse(date_month_year);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            // String eventStartInMillis = (String) date_month_year;
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", startdate.getTime());
            String eventEndInMillis = null;
            intent.putExtra("endTime", eventEndInMillis);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
            return currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
            this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
            this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
        }

        public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
            return currentWeekDay;
        }

    }
}
```

Also would like to mention that I **DID NOT** have to add GestureOverlayView in the xml file. I'm not going to include that code as I don't think it's neseccary. It looks like the one in my question without the GestureOverlayView part.

Comment: Hi Travis, and welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to consider reducing the length of your code snippet. As it stands, I don't foresee the code snippet as being useful to future visitors.

Comment: can I get complete project for the sample ... this looks interesting

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way to detect gestures I found is [GestureOverlayView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html)

You can use it like this
        GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);

```
    View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
    gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
    gestureOverlayView.setGestureColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    gestureOverlayView.setUncertainGestureColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    GestureLibrary gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, 
           R.raw.gestures);
    if (!gestureLib.load()) {
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(gestureOverlayView);
```

The gesture dispatcher looks like this

```
@Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);
    for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
        if (prediction.score > 1.0) {

            ControllerMain.getInstance().processSwipe(prediction.name);
            // Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            // .show();
        }
    }
}
```

In order to make gestureLib you should use gesture builder app. You can install it by this manual [Gestures Builder isn't installed on my emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740056/gestures-builder-isnt-installed-on-my-emulator) .

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. Just trying to implement this now and not going so well. Gonna post some new code on what I'm trying.

Comment: You should write "implement OnGesturePerformedListener" to your Actitvity decalration. "GestureLibrary gestureLib" move this variable declaration from "onCreate" to class members. "ControllerMain.getInstance().processSwipe(prediction.name);" - this is just an example, it's my own class, you should not copy that part :)

Comment: I'm going to revamp my question a little to clean in up. I've also implemented the listener. And yeah the controller Main line got me but I did finally get rid of it thinking it had something to do with your personal work.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured this thing out. I will post the good code in an answer when I clean it up a bit. I'm sure it won't look real clean to the pros. Thank you very much for leading me in right direction. I've been battling this for far to long.